# Three.js - Is Extra Mesh Material with Same Material Beneficial?

Tags: three.js

I am new to three.js. I know that you can combine multiple mesh materials into one mesh. What if the mesh is the same material? Would it add more detail? In otherwards, does the extra `mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material ); scene.add( mesh );` do anything beneficial? By the naked eye it's hard for me to tell.

```
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
   scene.add( mesh );

  mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  mesh.position.z = - 1500;
  scene.add( mesh );
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have a bit of a mix-up in the terminology. A mesh is an actual object in a scene, where as a material describes mesh's properties, which influence its shading. So creating a second mesh and adding it to a scene would result in a second object with provided geometry and material (i.e. presentation). The probable reason you don't see it may be because it's to far along Z-axis and got culled by camera's far clipping plane (a.k.a Z far).

And to the "is it beneficial" part. It's implementation dependent, but it may be beneficial for rendering performance, because draw calls for meshes sharing a material (and hence shader program and its parameters) can be coalesced together without redundant state changes, which is always good in WebGL (and OpenGl, for that matter).

Comment: You are incorrect in the context of Three.js. In addition to a mesh being a object, mesh term can be used in materials such as `MeshBasicMaterial`. In addition, you can have multiple materials for one single mesh object....with blending.

Comment: @dman Allow me to object. The word "mesh" in `MeshBasicMaterial` refers to it being **applied** to a mesh, i.e. specifically tied to a way meshes are drawn.

Comment: Yes, and I said 'multiple mesh materials into one mesh'

Comment: [`THREE.MultiMaterial`](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Materials/MultiMaterial) is such an example. Otherwise I agree with your answer. @dman your question is a bit vague/confusing. Can you rephrase? I am not sure what you are after...

Comment: If @dman's question is "mesh with a `MultiMaterial` vs. several meshes each with it's own material" then it seems that the only difference would be that a mesh with multimaterial gets all its geometry data to a single buffer for each attribute whereas for each separate mesh. This would be better for performance, but Three.js doesn't seem to take full advantage out of it. So in the end there is no performance difference, it just a matter of convenience. Shall I update the answer?